# Lambdifying Sympy function for only real numbers

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to convert output of a cubic equation to a function outside of sympy for the sake of performance.

```
import sympy as sp

u, x, y = sp.symbols('u x y')

eq = - y - sp.Integral(x**2, (x, 1, u))

solved = sp.solveset(eq.doit(), u, domain=sp.S.Reals)

lam = sp.lambdify(y, sp.solveset(eq.doit(), u, domain=sp.S.Reals))
```

Putting any number into `lam` throws
`NameError: name 'Intersection' is not defined`, even when importing `Intersection` specifically.

It seems like a bit much to ask for, I wouldn't expect this to work given the overhead, but is there a way to have this output, with `y` as input, as an external function where I don't need to rely on sympy to do the computation? I tried inputting a list of values as a `Matrix` object but this made the output more convoluted and it didn't seem to have the correct answers anywhere.

Comment: What does `sp.solveset(eq.doit(), u, domain=sp.S.Reals)` look like?  Where is `Intersection`?  I don't see the import.  Keep in mind that `lambdify` does a rather simple lexical conversion of the `sympy` expression into a `numpy` one.  `print(lam.__doc__)' should show the `numpy` function that your code produces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wasn't able to get the entire thing into an external function, but I was able to get a significant speed up by breaking it up into two separate bits that made it useable on a larger scale:

```
ed = eq.doit()

lam = sp.lambdify(y, ed)
vals = lam(np.arange(5000)).tolist()

output = [float(sp.solveset(i, domain=sp.S.Reals).args[0]) for i in vals]
```

this ended up being a 2x speedup from the alternative below

```
longtime = [sp.solveset(ed, u, domain=sp.S.Reals).subs(y, i) for i in np.arange(5000).tolist()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Running your code and answering my questions:

```
In [21]: 
    ...: u, x, y = symbols('u x y')
    ...: 
    ...: eq = - y - Integral(x**2, (x, 1, u))
    ...: 
    ...: solved = solveset(eq.doit(), u, domain=S.Reals)
    ...: 
    ...: lam = lambdify(y, solveset(eq.doit(), u, domain=S.Reals))

In [22]: solved
Out[22]: 
    ⎧3 ___________              ⎫
ℝ ∩ ⎨╲╱ │3⋅y - 1│ ⋅sign(1 - 3⋅y)⎬
    ⎩                           ⎭

In [23]: print(lam.__doc__)
Created with lambdify. Signature:

func(y)

Expression:

Intersection(FiniteSet(Abs(3*y - 1)**(1/3)*sign(1 - 3*y)), Reals)

Source code:

def _lambdifygenerated(y):
    return (  # Not supported in Python with SciPy:
  # FiniteSet
Intersection(FiniteSet(Abs(3*y - 1)**(1/3)*sign(1 - 3*y)), Reals))
```

`numpy/scipy` does not have any functions that implement `Intersection` or `FiniteSet`.  `sympy` cannot translate those functions.

===

With your change:

```
In [25]: ed=eq.doit()

In [26]: ed
Out[26]: 
   3        
  u        1
- ── - y + ─
  3        3

In [27]: 

In [27]: lam = lambdify(y,ed)

In [28]: print(lam.__doc__)
Created with lambdify. Signature:

func(y)

Expression:

-u**3/3 - y + 1/3

Source code:

def _lambdifygenerated(y):
    return (-1/3*u**3 - y + 1/3)


Imported modules:



In [29]: vals = lam(np.arange(10))

In [30]: vals
Out[30]: 
array([0.333333333333333 - 0.333333333333333*u**3,
       -0.333333333333333*u**3 - 0.666666666666667,
       -0.333333333333333*u**3 - 1.66666666666667,
       -0.333333333333333*u**3 - 2.66666666666667,
       -0.333333333333333*u**3 - 3.66666666666667,
       -0.333333333333333*u**3 - 4.66666666666667,
       -0.333333333333333*u**3 - 5.66666666666667,
       -0.333333333333333*u**3 - 6.66666666666667,
       -0.333333333333333*u**3 - 7.66666666666667,
       -0.333333333333333*u**3 - 8.66666666666667], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I made some clarifications to the goal, ie performance, and improved a bit of it as a potential answer.